# Почему в Linux Mint все папки в директории стали READ ONLY?

Tags: linux, linux-mint

Такая проблема, поставил на ноутбук рядом с виндой Linux Mint. И там есть жесткий диск D (остался с виндовса) который на файловой системе NTFS. Так вот вчера все файлы на данном диске были полностью доступны и с винды и с пингвина, а сегодня на Linux зашел и в этой директории все файлы и папки стали типа READ ONLY. В чем может быть проблема?? Эти файлы мне нужны в полном доступе на обеих ОС, да и с этим проблем не было до сегодня. Никакие права доступа и файловую систему не изменял. Так как все изначально работало то наверное проблема в чем то другом?? Спасибо.

Comment: Для безопасности, по умолчанию монтируется **ntfs** для чтения. Где-то опция маска монтирования находиться (вроде */etc/fstab*) нужно маску подредактировать.

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос вывод cat /etc/fstab